# ASP Core 3.1 Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have 2 `HttpGet` endpoints in a single controller. In order to make routes different I added parameter to the one of them. Look at the next code

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id:decimal}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(decimal id)
    {
        var user = await User.GetAsync(id);
        return Ok(user);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var users = await User.GetAllAsync();
        return Ok(users);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first endpoint is inaccessible. I hit the second endpoint even if I have `id` parameter in the query `http://localhost:80/api/user?id=1`.
Desired behavior is

1. Request `http://localhost:80/api/user?id=1` -> first endpoint
2. Request  `http://localhost:80/api/user` -> second endpoint

It must be something stupid-simple, because I'm sure I did the same way before, but now I stuck

Comment: To hit the first endpoint, you'd need `http://localhost:80/api/user/1`. The route-template you've set up expects `id` to be part of the route, not the query-string.

Comment: Yeah. Where do you even get the idea of a first endpoint given that you clearly and explictly define the routes and the only reoute you define has the id as part of the URL?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Ahaha, shame on me. Thank you sir! Don't even know how I made such a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Desired behavior is

> 1.Request `http://localhost:80/api/user?id=1` -> first endpoint

> 2.Request `http://localhost:80/api/user` -> second endpoint

If you'd like to match request(s) and map them to expected action(s) based on the querystring, you can try to implement a custom [ActionMethodSelectorAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionconstraints.actionmethodselectorattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1), like below.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class QueryStringConstraintAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string QueryStingName { get; set; }
    public bool CanPass { get; set; }
    public QueryStringConstraintAttribute(string qname, bool canpass)
    {
        QueryStingName = qname;
        CanPass = canpass;
    }
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        StringValues value;

        routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue(QueryStingName, out value);

        if (QueryStingName == "" && CanPass)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CanPass)
            {
                return !StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
            }

            return StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Apply to Action(s)

```
[HttpGet]
[QueryStringConstraintAttribute("id",true)]
[QueryStringConstraintAttribute("", false)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]decimal id)
{
    //var user = await User.GetAsync(id);
    //return Ok(user);
    
    //for test purpose
    return Ok("ActionWithQueryString");
}

[HttpGet]
[QueryStringConstraintAttribute("id", false)]
[QueryStringConstraintAttribute("", true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    //var users = await User.GetAllAsync();
    //return Ok(users);

    //for test purpose
    return Ok("ActionWithOutQueryString");
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

when you use

```
[HttpGet("{id:decimal}")]
```

it's mean your Url is like

```
http://localhost:80/api/user/{id}
```

OR

```
http://localhost:80/api/user/1
```